# python - pandas - boolean comparison - how to compare each value of a column against an integer?

Tags: python, pandas

Quick question with pandas.
Say i have a pandas dataframe storing the following value

```
timestamp              value                                   
2000-01-03 00:00:00       25  
2000-01-03 00:30:00      -10  
2000-01-03 01:00:00      100  
2000-01-03 01:30:00     -690  
2000-01-03 02:00:00      650  
2000-01-03 02:30:00      320  
2000-01-03 03:00:00      150  
2000-01-03 03:30:00      160
```

And i want to add a column that would be populated with a where a=1 if value>0 else -1

```
timestamp              value    a                                 
2000-01-03 00:00:00       25    1
2000-01-03 00:30:00      -10   -1
2000-01-03 01:00:00      100    1
2000-01-03 01:30:00     -690   -1
2000-01-03 02:00:00      650    1
2000-01-03 02:30:00      320    1
2000-01-03 03:00:00      150    1
2000-01-03 03:30:00      160    1
```

Is there a simple pandas syntax to do that?
I have tried plenty of code, not postinf here as its more confusing than anything...

Thanks!
(I'm changing the question to make it clearer, sorry about that..)

Comment: did you mean to write `if (price-entry_price)` ? because you're already looping on `exit_price`

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what your goal is, but the problem is the `trend_value = 1 if (exit_price-entry_price)> 0 else -1` line. `exit_price-entry_price` is a series, and you can't compare that against an integer. I suspect there's a better way using boolean masking. What's the desired output?

Comment: Yeah, I think the issue is that `data[i:i+tradebars].close` returns a series, not a value.

Comment: What is `tradebars` in `data[i:i+tradebars].close`?

Comment: hi, yes i want to compare a value, for instance 4, against an array of value, for instance [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] in which case (if value > [list of values]) the desired output would be [false,false,false,false,true,true,true]

Comment: I don't know if this is intended, but your loop skips the first entry in the dataframe. Could you explain the desired output?

Comment: tradebars=10 in that code.

Comment: I want to have a list, that i then need to convert to a dataframe, containing only 1 and -1. 1 if exit_price is > entry_price and -1 if entry_price>exit_price

Comment: From the code your posted, the `exit_price` is a series. `(exit_price-entry_price) > 0` will compare `entry_price` to each value in `exit_price`. `list(((exit_price-entry_price) > 0).values)` will return a list of True/False. Not sure if this is what you want. But definitely `(exit_price-entry_price)> 0` would not act as a condition in `if`.

Comment: mikeqfu: yes this does work:
`print list(((exit_price-entry_price) > 0).values)`
returns:
`[False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
[True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]
[False, True, False, True, True, True, True, True, True, True]`

 but when i insert the formula here:
`trend = 1 if list(((exit_price-entry_price) > 0).values) else -1`
`print trend`

it returns:
`1
1
1
1
1`
this is the problem...

Answer (score 2):

use [np.sign()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) method:

```
In [22]: df['a'] = np.sign(df.value)

In [23]: df
Out[23]:
             timestamp  value  a
0  2000-01-03 00:00:00     25  1
1  2000-01-03 00:30:00    -10 -1
2  2000-01-03 01:00:00    100  1
3  2000-01-03 01:30:00   -690 -1
4  2000-01-03 02:00:00    650  1
5  2000-01-03 02:30:00    320  1
6  2000-01-03 03:00:00    150  1
7  2000-01-03 03:30:00    160  1
8  2000-01-03 04:00:00      0  0   # <-----
```

NOTE: `np.sign` - returns `0` for `0` value, if you want to have `-1` for zero values - use [np.where()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
In [24]: df['a2'] = np.where(df.value > 0, 1, -1)

In [25]: df
Out[25]:
             timestamp  value  a  a2
0  2000-01-03 00:00:00     25  1   1
1  2000-01-03 00:30:00    -10 -1  -1
2  2000-01-03 01:00:00    100  1   1
3  2000-01-03 01:30:00   -690 -1  -1
4  2000-01-03 02:00:00    650  1   1
5  2000-01-03 02:30:00    320  1   1
6  2000-01-03 03:00:00    150  1   1
7  2000-01-03 03:30:00    160  1   1
8  2000-01-03 04:00:00      0  0  -1   # <----
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
list(trend.map(lambda x: 1 if x is True else -1))
```

If you don't want a list, just remove the `list()`. Then it returns a series.

If you want work on `trade`:

```
trade.trend.map(lambda x: 1 if x is True else -1)
```

would do the same work.